# ssh to server takes 15 seconds to connect

Tags: ssh

When I try to ssh to an Ubuntu server, using its numeric IP address, it takes about 15 seconds for the server to reply with a password request. I am connecting from my primary desktop Ubuntu 18.04 machine to the server, which is running Mythbuntu 14.04.

Once I connect, I can immediately ssh to any other computer on the system that accepts logins. When I ping the server's address, the response is instantaneous.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you please clarify your question? Are you asking why the initial SSH request is taking so long?

Comment: Yes I am. I should have also included that fact that this is new, starting in the last few days. For years prior to that the response was instantaneous.

Comment: Tried it, no help.

Comment: ssh 192.168.0.252 is the command to reach the server.

Comment: Please elaborate on the last paragraph. Are you saying you are able to instantaneously ssh from Myth to other machines? Are the 'other host computers on the system' referenced in the question also running 14.04? Also please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1170139/edit) your question with the output of `ping 192.168.0.252`